# Header image to show

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm trying to get a header image to show on a page of an app but it's not showing up and the _header seems to be greyed out in my code. I'm missing something I guess that I'm unsure of.  Edit: I need the header to show above the rows of content in the build.

```
 Widget _header() {
return new Container(
  child: new Row(
    children:<Widget>[
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'assets/classes-Image.png',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Extra code below:

````
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Learn How to Paint'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF202945),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/Profile-Photo.png',
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Katherine G.',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ```
````

Comment: Can you add the full code where you called your ```header()``` widget ? @ladyc

Comment: I didn't call it anywhere else because I didn't know to do so. I'm still pretty new to learning flutter

Comment: Ohokay. Please can you add the full code ? and is your image declared in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: image is declared in pubspec.yaml file. Having a bit of trouble getting the full code in the main post above. and it's too much to put in a comment apparently

Comment: okay. will be waiting for the full code snippet @ladyc

Comment: Seen the code. You want the header to show above the row ? @ladyc

Comment: Yep, right above the row.

Comment: Put ```header()``` write before the ```Row```. It wasn't. showing because you didn't include it in the ```ListView``` @ladyc

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if it helps ! @ladyc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing your `header` widget right before the `Row` widget.

The `header` is not showing because you didn't add it in the `ListView`.

I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be calling `_header()` from somewhere in your build function and give the result as a child to another widget. It being grayed out probably means you're not calling it.

Comment: I'm assuming then that where I need to call it would be where I actually want it to show up?